# mysql query for rating system

Tags: mysql, ranking, rating

```
select 
    user_id,
    @pos:=(@pos+1) as new_position,
    (coins+total_item_costs) as wealth 
from user_ledger 
join users using (user_id),(select @pos:=0) p 
ORDER BY wealth DESC 
limit 10;

+---------+--------------+------------+
| user_id | new_position | wealth     |
+---------+--------------+------------+
|      19 |           19 | 1112823871 |
|      11 |           11 |   13318047 |
|       8 |            8 |    7292407 |
|       6 |            6 |    6122746 |
|      27 |           27 |    5271889 |
|      23 |           23 |    5263050 |
|       9 |            9 |    5171734 |
|       3 |            3 |    5136092 |
|      15 |           15 |    5097488 |
|       4 |            4 |    5089487 |
+---------+--------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The new_position is incorrect..
What's wrong, guys? :)

ps. pls dont tell me to use temporary table

Answer (score 0):

Should do the ORDER BY beforehand the position.

```
SELECT user_id,@pos:=(@pos+1) as new_position,wealth FROM (
      select user_id,(coins+total_item_costs) as wealth from user_ledger join users 
      using (user_id) ORDER BY wealth DESC limit 10 ) a,(select @pos:=0) p
```

Comment: yes, this works, but i really dont want to use a temp table (even hidden).. can you suggest a query without it?

Comment: @IgorK: Perhaps it would help if you could explain *why* you don't want to use materialised tables?

Comment: @eggyal: for example, because i'm going to use the select as part of the 'INSERT INTO .. SELECT' statement and dont want to use the temp storage for the result :)

Comment: Please clearify your question what you really want and seems table you provided are missing because some columns do not exists in the table you provided

Comment: @IgorK, I have no idea how to make the query work without a sub query in which you are prefer. Hopefully others could shed some light on this.

Comment: @IgorK: It still isn't clear to me why you don't want to put `INSERT INTO ...` in front of the above `SELECT`.  All queries use "temp" storage (i.e. RAM) to some extent... what does it matter if the RAM used in this query represents a materialised table or not (after all, it's discarded as soon as the query completes)?

Comment: @eggyal: yes, you right. but theoretically thinking the overhead for the mat table creation is higher than just malloc..

Comment: @IgorK: Don't micro-optimise.  If you hit performance bottlenecks with this solution, you'll probably find there are better sources of improvement (indexing? partitioning? resource allocation? hardware upgrades? clustering?)

Comment: yes, you right again. thanks guys for the answers and your time :)